# Product Attribute value In Magento schema

Tags: magento2, database, product-attribute

Where is the product's attribute value is stored in magento 2 DB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it's an EAV property, here is how you can get the value:

SELECT * FROM el_magento.eav_attribute; -- get the attribute_id of your attribute

Depending on the property type you just have to do a SELECT on one of the following tables:
[image]

If you need further help feel free to ask and don't forget to up vote / mark as answer if this solved your issue ;)

Comment: how can i find attribute value of product ?

Comment: it's explained in the post above, to get the value you will need to first get the attribute Id with the first SELECT, this will give you a list where you can search for the attribute_code you defined when you created it, after that let's say it's from the data type "varchar" atributte you just have to do the following SELECT:

SELECT * FROM el_magento.catalog_product_entity_varchar where attribute_id = 138;

This will return the following columns:

value_id, attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value, value_id, id